# String interpolation for labels and amounts (align right)

Tags: vb.net, string-interpolation

I am trying to create some html which should align the amounts to the right.
The output html does not seem to comply with my code intentions. Any ideas?

```
sHtml += String.Format("<div>" & "Team earnings".PadRight(5, "."c) & dTeamEarnings.ToString.PadLeft(50 - dTeamEarnings.ToString.Length, "."c) & "</div>")


 sHtml += String.Format("<div>" & "Community earnings".PadRight(5, "."c) & dCommunityEarnings.ToString.PadLeft(50 - dCommunityEarnings.ToString.Length, "."c) & "</div>")
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: You should use CSS for this. If you really want to render plaintext then use `font-family: monospace;` otherwise use flexbox.

Comment: I would build an HTML table with two columns. Then set the text alignment for the columns in CSS. And if you are concatenating a lot of text you should use a StringBuilder